# Better MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, query-optimization

Here's one example, I have a Car, User, Member, and Dealer tables. At the moment I'm trying to get the name of a dealer who owns a car by matching their userids up

```
Select userid, name FROM `User` WHERE userid IN 
    (SELECT userid FROM 'Car' WHERE userid in 
        (SELECT userid FROM `Member` WHERE userid IN 
             (SELECT userid FROM `Dealer`)))
```

This does what I want but I can't help feel there's a better way of doing it? Currently the userid in Car is a FK of the userid in Dealer which is a FK of the userid in Member which is a FK of the userid in User which stores the name.

Can I go straight to getting all the userid's and names of dealers who's id is in the Car table, whilst making sure they're actually a Dealer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) instead of subqueries to fetch the data.

Try this:

```
SELECT U.userid, U.NAME 
FROM `User` U 
INNER JOIN Car C ON U.userid = C.userid 
INNER JOIN Member M ON C.userid = M.userid 
INNER JOIN Dealer D ON M.userid = D.userid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your schema is a downstream schema

Users -> Members -> Dealer -> Car

Good thing is you made all the possible keys that you need here.

So to selct anything in any table just go down stream from Users for example for the data you want

```
    Select * from `USER` u     
    where
    dealer.user_id = car.user_id and 
    member.user_id = dealer.user_id and 
    u.user_id = member.user_id
```

The reason i went upstream in matching records is because we want to make as few matching operations as possible. As you can see `user` table is supposed to contain the maximum records. So i match with `car` table and get all the `user_id` where there is a match in `dealer`. similarly i go from `dealer` to `member` and then to `user`. this means all the records of users will be matched with a lot fewer records that they would have been if i went from `users` to `members` to `dealer` to `car`.

But this is not fool proof solution. it will depend on your data. because it may be a case where one user may have multiple cars, then it would be better to go downstream.